# Spark job became incompatible with Google Dataproc

Tags: java, apache-spark, google-cloud-dataproc

I have this code that was working fine for months and stopped working about 2 months ago with Google Dataproc although I hadn't changed a single line.

I could reproduce the bug with just a few lines so I didn't have to post a huge block of code:

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("test");
JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);

JavaRDD<String> rdd = jsc.parallelize(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c"));
JavaPairRDD<String, String> pairs = rdd.flatMapToPair(value ->
        Arrays.asList(
                new Tuple2<>(value, value + "1"), 
                new Tuple2<>(value, value + "2")
        )
);
pairs.collect().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Then I get this obscure Exception:

```
WARN org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, test-cluster-w-1.c.test-project.internal): java.lang.AbstractMethodError: uk.co.test.CalculateScore$$Lambda$10/1666820030.call(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/util/Iterator;
        at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$$anonfun$fn$3$1.apply(JavaRDDLike.scala:142)
        at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$$anonfun$fn$3$1.apply(JavaRDDLike.scala:142)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
        at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:104)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:310)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1336)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:302)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1336)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:289)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1336)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1$$anonfun$13.apply(RDD.scala:893)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1$$anonfun$13.apply(RDD.scala:893)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1897)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1897)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 7, test-cluster-w-0.c.test-project.internal): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 2 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Container marked as failed: container_1475077182957_0001_01_000005 on host: sun-recommendations-evaluation-w-0.c.test-project.internal. Exit status: 50. Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1475077182957_0001_01_000005
Exit code: 50
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=50:
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:545)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:456)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:722)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:212)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


Container exited with a non-zero exit code 50

Driver stacktrace:
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1450)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1438)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1437)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1437)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1659)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1618)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1607)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:632)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1871)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1884)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1897)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1911)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:893)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:358)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:892)
        at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.collect(JavaRDDLike.scala:360)
        at org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.collect(JavaRDDLike.scala:45)
        at uk.co.test.CalculateScore.main(CalculateScore.java:50)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:729)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:185)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:210)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:124)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

If I run it locally with:

```
sparkConf.setMaster("local[2]")
```

Then it works fine and outputs:

```
(a,a1)
(a,a2)
(b,b1)
(b,b2)
(c,c1)
(c,c2)
```

These are my Spark dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default image used by Dataproc was recently upgraded to Spark 2.0 / Scala 2.11. This was changed in August and could potentially explain the difference.

[This page](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/dataproc-versions) details which versions of software packages are included in each Dataproc image release.

It may be sufficient to update your pom.xml with the following, recompile, and re-run your application

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

The [release notes](https://spark.apache.org/releases/spark-release-2-0-0.html) for Spark 2.0 contain [changes and removals](https://spark.apache.org/releases/spark-release-2-0-0.html#removals-behavior-changes-and-deprecations) between Spark 1.6 and 2.0.

As an alternative, you can still make use of the 1.0 image track using the following gcloud invocation:

```
$ gcloud dataproc clusters create --image-version 1.0 ...
```

When using an explicit image track, keep in mind that major/minor versions can be deprecated and eventually removed. The [Dataproc image versioning](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/versioning#image_version_and_cloud_dataproc_support) policy can be consulted for support timelines for image versions.

Comment: Thanks, Angus, it worked fine. Changing the version to 2.11 would require code changes, so in the meanwhile I had to go with `--image-version 1.0`. For anyone else with the same problem, I recommend setting the --image-version to the current one to avoid backward compatibility issues with future Dataproc upgrades.

Comment: Good point. I've also added a link to the image versioning support policy just to call out that image versions aren't supported indefinitely.